# Meaning: 'take on a macabre ring'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, metaphors

I've come across a confusing phrase.

> This former Belgian possession is the most Christian country in Africa, boasting the highest percentage of churches per head of population, with 65 percent of Rwandans professing Roman Catholicism and another 15 percent adhering to various Protestant sects. The words “per head” ***took on a macabre ring*** in 1992, when at a given signal the racist militias of “Hutu Power,” incited by state and church, fell upon their Tutsi neighbors and slaughtered them en masse.

Though having some somewhat approximate guesses, I can't make sure what the bol italic phrase above exactly mean in this context.

Should I take it literally and come up with something like "wearing a death-resembling (horrible) ring"? Or should I consider any implications or metaphors?

Actually, I can't associate "take on" with "ring" in this sentence. Hence all the confusion.

Comment: To have a certain "ring" is to show the characteristics of: *The name has a nice ring to it* means the name sounds nice. *The words “per head” took on a macabre ring* is a way of saying that the phrase started sounding rather macabre (conjuring up images of death or serious harm). *Ring* here is not in the sense of a circular object; instead, think of a bell "ringing." HTH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The words “per head” took on a macabre ring.

The horrific and well-known Rwandan Genocide of Tutsi by their Hutu neighbours involved beheading among other maiming actions. A common tool to kill was the machete. In retrospect this event now ties the words “per head” to these killings instead of just a count.

Per head now sounds like death.

1. macabre ring: a death-like sound;
2. took on: acquired.

Comment: This doesn't address the sentence A.K. doesn't understand at all.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet I've added "Per head now sounds like death."

Comment: That still does not address the question at all. The question is about what _took on_ and _ring_ mean.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet macabre ring: make a death-like sound; took on: acquired. A. K. is well-championed.

Answer (score 0):

The origin of macabre is unclear and the meaning is vague. Sometimes it means connected somehow with death, sometimes it simply means horrible as in your phrase.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/macabre